# Trigger a function from an iframe but execute as if triggered from parent document?

Tags: javascript

I've got a parent page, with a child iframe... When clicking on a specific button inside the child iframe, I want a function to trigger as if it were originating from the parent document itself.

The function chain I have is rather long, and dependent no a lot of variables and what not. When I trigger the function (by adding onclick to the button in the child frame), the chained functions fail because the variables are not recognized (since they don't exist within the child DOM's scope).

Any thoughtful solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function `parentFunction()` is defined in the parent frame you can call it from the child frame by saying `parent.parentFunction();` (and pass it any parameters it needs for values defined in the child).

(By the way, it's probably not a good sign that you have a chain of functions that are all dependent on variables that I assume from your description are globals.)

Comment: Ah... I knew you could select elements from the parent using parent.eleName, but I didn't know you could do that for functions too... This effectively solved my problem... Oh, and why is it not a good sign that my chain of functions have dependent, global variables? Not to argue, but you might have an interesting point...

Comment: @Abhishek - I avoid referencing the parent frame's elements directly; I don't like my child frame to depend on the parent's HTML structure. Instead of `parent.eleName` I'd say `parent.getData()` (or whatever name is appropriate) and leave it to the parent to decide where that data comes from. As for global variables, there's a school of thought that says they should be kept to a minimum because they can lead to maintenance problems where different functions assume they are for different purposes, or they clash with third-party libraries, etc. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped.